# How to remove multiple hyperlink displayed from wizard (oddo 9)

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

created wizard to input data from user, when i click button, 
[wizard input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri3lN.png)
its will open new form by click view button

but in new form header, multiple hyperlink will displayed (from previous input data)
[multiple hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obY86.png)

i want only active/last input data will displayed on hyperlink like this

how to do ?
my code is like this to redirect other form

```
 return {
        'name': string_title,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'sales_report_custom.sales_data',
        'domain' : domain,
        'view_type': 'form',
        'target': 'self',
        'view_mode': 'graph,pivot,tree',
        'context':{'date_transaction_from':date_from, 'date_transaction_to':date_to, 'date_transaction': date_trans, 'salesperson':salIds, "search_default_date_transaction":'1', "period_filter":period_fil},

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Update your question with attempted/tried code.

Comment: i update my question with code..thanks